# How to create tagboxes in Redactor.js editor similar in behavior with email tags when composing in Gmail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor

I'm trying to create similar tag boxes in [redactor.js](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) using an external button:

[image]

I was able to insert the html and add css to it with jquery.

`redactor.insertHtml('<div class="templateTag">' + inputValue + '</div>');`

Right now I'm not able to disable the cursor and the possibility to delete content when clicking the element (to simulate a "select", as it is in gmail)

Is there a way to disable the blinking cursor (so will not allow user to delete the content)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to use RadactorJS to do that. You can use [Typehead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js) and [Tag Manager](https://github.com/max-favilli/tagmanager).

Comment: I use Redactor.js, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Yes but RedactorJS isn't made for that.